# Levy upward in $L^2$

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, martingales

Let $(F_n)_n$ be a filtration and $F=\sigma(\cup_n F_n)$.
Let $Z$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}Z^2<\infty$.
Let $X_n=\mathbb{E}[Z|F_n]$.

**Given:**
If $X_n\to Z$ a.s. then $||X_n-Z||_2\to0$ iff $||X_n||_2\to ||Z||_2$.
For a $\pi$-system $\Pi$ such that $\sigma(\Pi)\subset F$, if we have $\int_A Yd\mathbb{P}=\int_A Xd\mathbb{P}$ for all $A\in \Pi$ then
$$Y=\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(\Pi)].$$

> How do we show that $||X_n-Z||_2\to0$?

I know that
$$||X_n||_2=\left(\mathbb{E}X_n^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z|F_n]^2]\right)^{1/2}.$$
By conditional Jensen I thought that then $||X_n||_2\leq\left(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z^2|F_n]]\right)^{1/2}=\left(\mathbb{E}[Z^2]\right)^{1/2}=||Z||_2$.
Is this correct? How do I continue from here?

Comment: What do you know about limit theorems for martingales? Note that $(X_n)_n$ is an $L^2$-bounded martingale, hence .....

Comment: @saz Then it converges in $L^2$?

Comment: Yes, it does.. so all what remains to do is to identity the limit, let's call it $X_{\infty}$. To this end you have to use that $$ \int_F Z \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X_n \, d\mathbb{P}$$ for any $F \in F_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You can let $n \to \infty$ on the right-hand side (why?) to obtain $$\int_F Z \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P}$$ for all $F \in F_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Conclude that $X_{\infty}=Z$ a.s.

Comment: @saz Why can we let $n\to\infty$ in $\int_F X_n d\mathbb{P}$? Is it because of monotone convergence and the martingale property?

Comment: I don't see any monotonicity here, do you...? You know that $X_n \to X_{\infty}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$; use this to deduce that the integrals converge.

Comment: @saz Since $X_n\to X_\infty$ in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ we have that $\int (X_n-X_\infty)^2 d\mathbb{P}\to0$. I don't see yet why then $\int_F X_nd\mathbb{P}\to \int_F X_\infty d\mathbb{P}$ for $F\in F_n$

Comment: Note that $$\int_F (X_n-X_{\infty})^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \int (X_n-X_{\infty})^2 \, d\mathbb{P}.$$ Now use the fact that $Y_n \to Y$ in $L^2$ implies $\int Y_n \, d\mathbb{P} \to \int Y \, d\mathbb{P}$.